# PrimeFaces 5.1 - Lost mask in InputMask Component with Onblur Action

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, input-mask

I need some help.

I'm using the PrimeFaces 5.1 and I have a problem in the component , this component I have a mask only for numeric (?99999999) and in 'onblur' action I call a method.

My problem is that the component is not recognizing the mask '?99999999' and is always required me to enter the all 8 numbers, if the number entered is less than eight it's goes through life cycle validation and will not let me continue.

I need use this mask for 1-8 numbers and call a onblur after, without this validation, it will be a problem in Primefaces 5.1?

```
                    <p:inputMask id="inputTextStageCodeId" 
                                 value="#{Step.stepSearch.step.stage.id.stageCode}" 
                                 mask="?99999999"
                                 title="#{msg['common.stageCode.title']}"
                                 immediate="true" 
                                 size="8" 
                                 >
                        <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this"
                                             immediate="true" 
                                             update="stageDescriptionDropDownId, inputTextStepCodeId, :messagesId" 
                                             listener="#{Step.doFindStageCodeSearch}" />
                    </p:inputMask>
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: tried a newer version?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not work with another version, I need to find a way to work with version 5.1, you have any idea how?

Comment: Try to remove `immediate` attributes and if you need a 1-8 number the mask would be `9?9999999`.

Comment: Hi Miguel, I've tried, it has the same behavior, instead of using 9?9999999 it uses 9999999